# Matrix Representation Problem 2

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me solve this Problem here?

[image]

> And what is the monomial Basis, is it just a polynomial of degree 2 or less?
>
> And for example in order to calculate $L_{W_1 \leftarrow V_1}$,should I firstly put the Basis of $V_1$ in $L$ and then calculate it with respect to the Basis of $W_1$ (which should just give the matrix itsself,as $W_1$ is the standard Basis)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the problem i think $\mathcal{P}_2$ denotes the $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspace of polynomials with real coefficents of degree $\leq 2$. Lets take $p = a_2 X^2 +a_1 X +a_0$  in $\mathcal{P}_2$. Then the monomial basis $V_1$ is the familiy $(X^0 =1, X, X^2)$, as you can see $p$ is a linear combination of the basis elements.

Lets compute the matrix representation $L_{W_1 \leftarrow V_1}$. As you have said, we need to plug in the basis $V_1$ into our given map, recall that it is enough for a homomorphism of vector spaces to evaluate on basis elements, so

$L(X^0)= \begin{bmatrix} X^0(1) + 2 X^0(1) & 4({X^0})^{\prime}(0)\\
3X^0(2) - ({X^0})^{\prime \prime}(0) & ({X^0})^{\prime \prime}(1)+ ({X^0})^{\prime}(1)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\
3 &  0 \end{bmatrix} = 3 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
0 &0 \end{bmatrix} + 3 \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\
1 &0 \end{bmatrix} = \\ =3 w_1 + 0 w_2 +3 w_3 + 0 w_4$

So the first column in our matrix $L_{W_1 \leftarrow V_1}$ is just $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\  0 \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. I hope you got the concept, i will leave the rest of the computations up to you.

Comment: How would then look the matrix if we put $V_2$ in $L$? should we then have 3 different polynomial which we have to put in L ? Like $V_2$= (1, 1 + x, 1+x+x^2)?

Comment: And I think that you have a mistake calculating $L(X^0)$ = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 4 \\
31 &  5 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: regarding your first comment, yes, thats what you would to have put in. Regarding your second comment: $X^0 =1$, so at any point you might eveluate $X^0$, the value will be $1$. Furthermore the derivative of a constant is  zero,so you have $1+2 =3$ in the upper left corner, $0$ in the upper right corner, since $4$ times $0$ is $0$ and so on...

Comment: But if you put$ V_2$ in $L$ how would the matrix look like?would you then have 3 matrices, as firstly you put L(1) then L(1+x) an L(1+x+x^2)?

Comment: No, you proceed as in my computations, first you plug in 1, then you can write $L(1)$ as a linear combination of basis vectors of say $W_1$. The coefficients in this expression gives u the FIRST column in the matrix $L_{W_1 \leftarrow V_2}$, if you plug in $L(1+X)$ and write the value as a linear combination of the basis of the range, these coeffcients give you the SECOND column in the matrix $L_{W_1 \leftarrow V_2}$ and so on. Can you compute $L_{W_1 \leftarrow V_1}(X)$ for me?

Comment: I think I got it. so $L_{W_1 \leftarrow V_1}$=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & 2 \\
0 &  4 &0 \\ 3 & 6 &10 \\ 0 & 1 & 4\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Thank you very much !!!

Comment: You got it, good job. Glad I could help.

Comment: I read that a matrix monomial ordering is a total ordering if we have $Ker A \cap \mathbb Z^n=0$, can you please tell me why is that?